# .NET Standard: assembly's manifest definition does not match assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

As soon as I update any libraries that use `.NET Standard` (and haven't used it before), I get the following:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

with package.config

```
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Tried with 4.3.3.0 in the Web.config binding, but same error.
Using VS 2017 latest.

**Update**

We found it's down to upgrading `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` from v1 to v2. As soon as going from 1.1.2 to 2.0.2, the above error shows up.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: Same as specified in packages.config - 4.6.1

Comment: Is the binding redirect inside a runtime section and an assemblybinding section? Making sure the web config is correctly setup.

Comment: Yes it is, right in the middle of all the other bindings... :/

Comment: Do you have a repro for this that I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I am targetting 4.6.2, I installed System.Net.Http version 4.3.3 via Nuget and I was getting the same error.

When I changed my Binding redirect to use:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The errors went away and I can build and test without issue again.